# How could mix noise and texture by Opengl shader?

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, fragment-shader, perlin-noise

I want to put my noise texture(like perlin noise or something else) on image texture,

1. when i add noise texture and image texture directly,it will make the src image texture light,

   ```
   fragColor = vec4(image_texture+noise_texture,1.0);
   ```
2. when i use mix func, some arear will be darker,

   ```
   fragColor = mix(image_texture,noise_texture,factor)
   ```

neither effect is good. 
I've referred to a code that use the alpha channel for overlay directly,but it seems to change the background of the GLFW window directly to the image texture,because its shader doesn't use texture,just use alpha channel like this:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
```

which I don't know how to do too. So,is there any good way to mix noise and texture?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please use backtick `\`` instead of single-quote `'` for formating code

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Try: `fragColor = vec4(image_texture + (noise_texture-0.5)*factor, 1.0);`